# Code to read Sum total per row works but need to ignore non Integer values and still some up with total. I also need to find grand total

Tags: c#

I have the following code but I need help to make the code ignore a non integer value in a row. Currently It calculates sum per each row, but if it stops when it meets non integer value. also how can i get grand total of all rows?

My Input file Looks Like This

50,22,30,10,50,5,40

25,10,10,46,16,17,90

15,c80x,2

x,2,3,

public class Program
    {

```
    static string currentLine; //variable for holding the current line that has been read from the file
    static int[] theList; // array to hold integer values read from the theLine
    static int LineNumber = 1; //A count keeping the current line's number
    static int theSum; //Variable to hold the sum of the numbers successfully ready from the file

    static int total;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fileStream = new FileStream(@"InputData.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            //string line;



            while ((currentLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                Add(currentLine); // process the line
            }


        }
        Console.ReadLine();

        fileStream.Dispose();//Release the file
    }




    public static void Add(string numbers)
    {

       if (numbers.Contains(";")) //Check if line contains semi-colon as the delimiter
        {
            theList = numbers.Trim().Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();


            //add input elements to array excluding the ; character
        }
        else if (numbers.Contains(",")) //Check if the line contains comma as the delimiter
        {
            theList = numbers.Trim().Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray(); 
            // add input elements to array excluding the , character
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        theSum = theList.Sum();



        Console.WriteLine("The sum of the numbers entered at line : " +
          LineNumber.ToString() + " is : " + theSum);
        LineNumber++;



    }
```

Comment: What does your input file look like?

Comment: @px06 Check Now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using *Linq*, your task is one Linq has been designed for:

```
   using System.Linq;

   ...

   public static void Main(string[] args) {
     var result = File
       .ReadLines(@"InputData.txt")
       .Select(line => line
          .Split(new char[] { ',', ';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          .Select(item => {
             int v;
             bool parsed = int.TryParse(item, out v);

             return new {
               value = v,
               isParsed = parsed,
             }; 
           })
          .Where(item => item.isParsed)
          .Sum(item => item.value));

     int lineIndex = 0;
     long grandTotal = 0;

     foreach (var sum in result) {
       Console.WriteLine( 
         $"The sum of the numbers entered at line {lineIndex + 1} is: {sum}");  

       lineIndex += 1;
       grandTotal += sum;
     }  

     Console.Write($"Grand total is {grandTotal}");  
   }
```

Comment: `Select(item => int.Parse(item)` is semantically identical to the OP's `Select(int.Parse)`. And since `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` only removes empty entries, but not non-integer entries, the problem remains unsolved.

Comment: @Sefe: I see, thank you! Haven't noticed the question edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`. You can change this part...

```
numbers.Trim().Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray()
```

...to this:

```
numbers.Trim().Split(',')
    .Select(text => {
        int result;
        bool isNumeric = Int32.TryParse(text, out result);
        return new { result, isNumeric };
    })
    .Where(entry => entry.isNumeric)
    .Select(entry => entry.result)
    .ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

better use `int.TryParse()` for ensuring you wont get an exception and the loop halts:
Insetad of:

```
 theList = numbers.Trim().Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Use:

```
string[] list=numbers.Trim().Split(',');
List<int> theList=new List<int>();
foreach (string item in list)
{
  int result;
  if (int.TryParse(out result)
  {
       theList.Add(result);
  }
}
```

Also dont throw any exception (leave else blank) because again if it enters else it would halt the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I really like this problem because it makes great use of one of my standard library methods.

So lets first start by preventing exceptions when a string is not a valid number.

```
public static class IntExt
{
    public static int? ParseNullable(string text)
    {
        int result;
        return int.TryParse(text, out result) ? result : (int?)null;
    }
}
```

This method returns null when the string isn't a number.  This is super easy to query against.  So we just run a simple LINQ query to get our answer.

```
var result = numbers.Trim().Split(',').Sum(x => IntExt.ParseNullable(x) ?? 0);
```

In the above section of code I only want to point out that `?? 0` means "Or if null return 0".  It's a new operator in C# 6.

Finally we just need to tally the lines.

```
int total;
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
    while ((currentLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        total += currentLine.Trim().Split(',').Sum(x => IntExt.ParseNullable(x) ?? 0); 
//total now contains the grand total
```